# Rails model methods availability in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my model which should detect the User Agent. How can I make it available to all my controller methods?

Model:

```
  def is_iphone_request?
       if request.user_agent =~ /iPhone/
       return true
     end
  end
```

Controller (throws an error):

```
def index
  @user_agent = is_iphone_request?
end
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the method in your `ApplicationController` instead of in a model.

Comment: Can you explain why you would put this in ApplicationController?  I had the exact same instinct to do as the questioner.  It seems logical to put this in the model

Comment: Because `request` is not accessible in models. Besides, handling request variables is typically something that should be done by the controller, not the model.

Comment: Ok.  I think I see the difference between his situation and mine.  Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've put the request user-agent check on the model--it seems like a controller centric behavior. And there is a request attribute IN a controller that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Though `request` will *not* be available in the model (you will get a `NameError` with the following code), your current problem is that the controller is throwing a `NoMethodError` because you are missing `self.` on the method definition. Make it a class method (by adding `self.`):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.is_iphone_request?
   if request.user_agent =~ /iPhone/
     return true
   end
end
```

Then, in your controller, you can use:

```
MyModel.is_iphone_request?
```

But like I said, you will get a `NameError` because `request` is not available in the model.

Your method `is_iphone_request?` should probably live in your `ApplicationController` (where it can be a regular `private` method). You can also trim it down:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  private
  def is_iphone_request?
    request.user_agent =~ /iPhone/ ? true : false
  end
end
```

Then, in your controller, you can use:

```
is_iphone_request?
```